# Ограничения для пуша в мастер

Tags: github

Есть ли возможность на github сделать ограничение на push в мастер (для всех, включая админов) при этом разрешить с админскими правами проходить ревью без approve?

Мне кажется, что ответ лежит где-то среди этих галочек. Так ли это? Реализуемо ли это?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: картина мелкая, галочки не читаются

Comment: @Эникейщик так она кликабельная